# Evaluating Istio rule match using GreaterThan / LessThan

Tags: istio, telemetry

Looking at the capabilities of Istio Rule.match, .. https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/istio.policy.v1beta1/#Rule , how would one match on GreaterThan / LessThan , as opposed to just existance / equality checks

Eg. How would I be able to achieve something like this (header value > 24)

```
spec:
  match: match((request.headers["some-header"] | 24) >"24")
```

Comment: What Can I see from documentation is that the match field is with string type so ">" by itself might not be recognized.

Comment: Yes. I wonder what alternatives istio provides to achieve non string comparisons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule mentioned in the question will not work because of mismatched attribute types.

---

However, it is possible to do with **Common Expression Language** ([CEL](https://github.com/google/cel-spec)).

You can enable CEL in istio by using the `policy.istio.io/lang` annotation (set it to `CEL`).

Then by using [Type Values](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#type-values) from the [List of Standard Definitions](https://github.com/google/cel-spec/blob/master/doc/langdef.md#list-of-standard-definitions) we can use create functions to parse values into different types.

For example: `int()` that gets a `string` and produces an `int` that we can 
then compare with `_>_` `(int, int) -> bool`.